# How to Disable Auto loading in Jquery Ajax tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tabs

I am facing one problem due to auto-loading in Jquery Ajax tabs. How can I disable the autoloading of the tabs. It hang up my browser.  Below is scenario of my requirement.

On the 1st tab it load the category such as

- Category 1
- Category 2
- Category 3

When I click on the Category 1 link then it open the tab 2 and content for the tab 2 is as below

- Sub Category 1
- Sub Category 2
- Sub Category 3

When I click on the Sub Category 1 link then it will open the tab 3

But I want to disable the auto loading in Jquery Ajax tabs

Can you please guide me how can I implement it.

Comment: could you post the relevant code here/ create a jsfiddle.http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I am using the jquery ajax tabs so how to disable the auto loading in that

Comment: youe requirement is that when category is clicked it needs to load the tab but should not load the elements in it? if thats the case, then when do u expect it to load the components over it ?

Comment: [example link](http://jsfiddle.net/X8V4C/)

Comment: I just need to stop the auto loading of the page

Comment: rest of the thing is working perfect. What jquery ajax tabs do it auto load there internal page every time. So Want to stop that auto loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out the issue and need to comment the below code

```
    if ( this.active.length ) {
            this.load( options.active );
        }
```

in the file jquery-ui.js file

It stop auto loading ...

Answer (score 3):

Another quick fix (working in jQuery.ui v1.11.2)

```
jQuery.ui.tabs.prototype._isLocal = function() { return true; };
```

Use before calling .tabs().
This tricks jQuery.ui into believing the tab is already loaded. Needed if you are using virtual document paths at your site which remap the url path to another document via .htaccess (or some other means). _isLocal does not correctly identify that the tab is local with virtual paths in effect and tries to load the tab content even when it is explicitly in the document.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `beforeLoad` event:

```
$(".selector").tabs({
    beforeLoad: function(event, ui) {
        // if the target panel is empty, return true
        return ui.panel.html() == "";
    }
});
```